# Detect that Bootstrap carousel ended

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-carousel

I would like to know if there is any way to detect when the Bootstrap carousel finishes running, since I need to execute a function when the carousel reached the last element.

I apply here the question to a comment to see it in a better format:

```js
const carousel = document.getElementById("carouselContainer");

carousel.addEventListener("slid.bs.carousel", function (e) {
    if (e.direction === "right" && e.to === elements.length - 1) {
      // Take an action
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#events): you should compare `from` and `to` according to `direction`.

```js
if (direction == 'left' && to == 0) {
    startReached();
}

if (direction == 'right' && to == elements.length - 1) {
    endReached();
}
```

Comment: Hi Justinas, thanks for answering. You mean to do something like this?
const carousel = document.getElementById("container");

carousel.addEventListener("slid.bs.carousel", function (e) {
    if (e.direction === "right" && e.to === elements.length - 1) {
      // // Take an action
    }
  });

Comment: Yes, something like this